# How to let python3 import graph-tool installed by Homebrew?

Tags: python, homebrew, graph-tool

I tried to use Homebrew to install [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/), but the python3 cannot find it.

```
    brew tap homebrew/science
    brew install graph-tool
```

It is said that the package is installed in `homebrew/science/graph-tool-2.22_1`, where I only found `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-science/graph-tool.rb`.

When I tried to import graph-tool in python3, it shows that 
`from graph_tool.all import *`
`ImportError: No module named 'graph_tool'`

I am using python3.

`which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3`

Is there a way I can use the graph_tool package installed in Homebrew?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, how did you fix this problem?

Comment: I found that installing python using Homebrew causes Import issues, things work better when installed from http://python.org/downloads

Answer (score 5):

Another solution that worked for me is simply creating a symlink from graph-tool to python side packages

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/graph-tool/2.26_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/graph_tool /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Answer (score 4):

A quick solution.

To Check brew installed package path in the console,

`brew --prefix graph-tool`

Then at the beginning of the code, append the path.

```
    import sys
    sys.path.append('/usr/local/Cellar/graph-tool/2.22_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')
    from graph_tool.all import *
```

Answer (score -1):

I was in a virtualenv when this happened to me. Make sure homebrew installs graph-tool with the same python version you want to use for your virtualenv, then recreating the virtualenv with `--system-site-packages` will allow it to access system packages, including graph-tool installed through homebrew.

See: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/5741