# Graph-tool installed but can't be imported

Tags: python, python-2.7, homebrew, graph-tool

I installed Graph-tool via homebrew

```
$ brew --prefix graph-tool
/usr/local/opt/graph-tool
```

But I still get error when trying to import it.

I have read related posts [How to let python3 import graph-tool installed by Homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521774/how-to-let-python3-import-graph-tool-installed-by-homebrew) and tried all the solutions provided there, but none of them fixed it. Adding the path in python doesn't work, re-run homebrew as below doesn't either.

```
$ brew install graph-tool --with-python2.7
Warning: homebrew/science/graph-tool 2.26_1 is already installed
```

I usually use python via anaconda, but I also tried importing it from python console and it didn't work.

Comment: What kind of import error occurred? I looked at the link to the other SO question and the answer by Kevin, although hacky, should explicitly add a link to enable import of graph-tool.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was in a virtualenv. Recreating the virtualenv with `--system-site-packages` allows it to access system packages, including graph-tool installed through homebrew.

Source: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/5741